# Retry Redis operation when connection is down

Tags: python, redis

I want to write code to insert data into Redis.  First, it should connect the Redis server and retry if that fails.  Once it connects, it should execute commands like `hset()` and `set()`.  How can I retry these commands if the connection goes down?

This is what I have so far, it just handles retries during the connect step.

```
while cnt < 11:
    try:
        r.ping()
        break

    except redis.ConnectionError:
        time_sleep = cnt * 5
        time.sleep(time_sleep)
        r = redis.Redis(host='10.23.*.*', port=6379, db=0)
        cnt += 1
        print cnt
if cnt == 11:
     sys.exit(-1)
r.hset(field,keys,1)
```

Comment: If by "abnormal case" you mean any kind of exception thrown when trying to do anything with Redis - than yes, `try ... except`

Answer (score 4):

You can expand on your initial counter idea to apply it to any operation.

```
max_retries = 10
count = 0

r = redis.Redis(host='10.23.*.*', port=6379, db=0)

def try_command(f, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except redis.ConnectionError:
            count += 1

            # re-raise the ConnectionError if we've exceeded max_retries
            if count > max_retries:
                raise

            backoff = count * 5

            print('Retrying in {} seconds'.format(backoff)
            time.sleep(backoff)

            r = redis.Redis(host='10.23.*.*', port=6379, db=0)

# this will retry until a result is returned
# or will re-raise the final ConnectionError
try_command(r.hset, field, keys, 1)
```